# How to split specific line using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, string

I have the following string:

```
"body":"The Example 1",(sample),{sample},"sample",&sample,"body":"The Example 2",(sample),{sample},"sample",&sample
```

From above string, I need to extract

- `"The Example 1"` into variable `string1`
- `"The Example 2"` into variable `string2`

**I'm using the following code**

```
 Pattern comment1 = Pattern.compile("(?<=\")(?:\\\\.|([\"body\"]))*(?=\")", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
 Matcher matchComm = comment1.matcher(responce.toString());
```

I am not getting proper results.

Comment: Why are you trying to match a backslash there? ("\\\\")

Comment: im matching inverted commas "" because identify the  body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```
(?<=:")((?=",|"$)|.)+
```

- `(?<=:")` is a possetive look behind for `:"`.
- `(?=",|"$)` is a possetive look ahead for `",` or `"$` where `$` marks the end of the line/file.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qT4oO6/2

**EDIT1:**

The following code could be used to produce an array, where every position in the array is a separate match from the input string.

```
String input = PUT YOUR STRING HERE!;
String pattern = "(?<=:\")((?=",|\"$)|.)+";
ArrayList<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while(m.find()){
  out.add(m.group());
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Since you after writing the question clarified that you indeed wanted to only mach the string following the "body" tag, the following regex would be required instead:

```
(?<="body":")((?=",|"$)|.)+
```

Also if the field following the "body" tag is allowed to be empty, the `+` should be swapped for a `*`:

```
(?<="body":")((?=",|"$)|.)*
```

Comment: thanks bro and how can i assign 2 outputs separately like this `String str1 =first output String  str 2 = second output `

Comment: @VinuVish Try that :)

Comment: than-you so much  @Olian04

Comment: i getting error in `Matcher m = p.matcher( {{String}} );`ERROR : Array initialize is not allows hear

Comment: @VinuVish I've changed the example to better clarify what i meant.

Comment: thanks but same as this i have done its not working .i think if condition is not working when i print array its its shows empty

Comment: @VinuVish looks like i made a fool of my self. This should now work. Sorry for the confusion i caused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120515/discussion-between-vinu-vish-and-olian04).

Comment: @Olian04 very solid answer. Deserves more +1

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do with a better regex (no need of lookbehinds / lookaheads). Add `(?i)` to make it case insensitive.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "\"body\":\"The Example 1\",\"body\":\"The Example 2\"";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"body\":\"(.*?)\""); // Capture everything after "body"
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
The Example 1
The Example 2
```

Comment: thanks for the reply  when the string is like this what should we do `"body":"The Example 1",(sample),{sample},"sample",&sample,"body":"The Example 2"`

Comment: This would limit the regex to only target values proceeding a `body` section. Although shown in code, this was never expressed as a criteria in the question.

Comment: @VinuVish - Do you only want data which is following the "body" part?

Comment: @VinuVish - The regex I used above works in that case as well